# What is required to call a controller in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I'm creating a simple blog with Codeigniter. But I'm having trouble calling another controller besides the default controller.

The following URL takes me to the default controller as specified in my config/routes.php.

```
blog/index.php
```

According to the documentation, simply appending the name of another controller saved in controllers/ is all that is needed:

```
blog/index.php/blog_login
```

Here is my controller class, named blog_login.php:

```
class Blog_login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'It works!';
    }
}
```

But doing this throws a 404 error, which makes me feel that I'm missing something. Is there something else that I am supposed to configure before trying to access a different controller?

Comment: Have you added it to the routes?

Comment: He doesn't need to add it to routes. 

`application/controllers/blog_login.php` should be accessable through `blog/index.php/blog_login`

Comment: @Steven Lu That's the thing, I'm doing this on a fresh installation of Codeigniter just to make sure that I can do it in the simplest conditions possible.

Comment: @JimJohnson: Be sure you are properly extending `CI_Controller` by adding the construct: `function __construct(){ parent::__construct(); }`

Comment: @Colin I have a properly written constructor, but I chose not to include it into the code for this question. Does having symlinks have anything to do with my routing issues?

Answer (score 0):

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html Read this properly, it couldn't be clearer.

> According to the documentation, simply appending the name of another
>   controller saved in controllers/ is all that is needed

This is not true. If you want to call another controller 'Blog_login', you simply put the name of the controller as the first segment of the url:

```
domain.com/index.php/blog_login
```

This will never work:

```
blog/index.php/blog_login
```

Index.php (unless you remove it via .htaccess) always follows right after your domain.com

Finally, you don't need to specify routes unless you're doing something non standard. So

`domain.com/index.php/blog_login` - calls the index() function in your Blog_login controller
`domain.com/index.php/blog` - calls the index() function in your blog controller
`domain.com/index.php/blog/search` - calls the search() function in your blog controller.

None of the above examples need an entry in routes.php

Comment: Yes, the docs are very clear. It turns out that my textmate was not saving the files properly after I installed a bundled. I had it right all along >.<

Comment: @JimJohnson, then perhaps it's better to close the question all together, since essentially there wasn't a problem.  No need for people to try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

When u call:

```
blog/index.php/blog_login
```

you're really calling a method called "blog_login" in your "blog" controller. If you want to call another controller, it must have the following structure:

```
controller_name/controller_method
```

So, if you wanna call your blog_login controller just call it like this:

```
blog_login/
```

Note: Sometimes it's necessary to add the base_url() to your URL in order to make CI understand correctly the URL.